# Minimum movement per frame

Tags: game-physics

When it comes to calculating movement in a game engine, each frame I update the position of the player, based on his speed. If I try to be realistic in my calculations, I end up with a displacement per frame that is so small that movement overall doesn't occur or, when accelerating, occurs only discontinuously.
Here's an example:

**frame rate = 60 fps**

**window height = 600 px**

**scale = 10px = 1 m**

**speed = 2 m/s = 0.03... m/frame (Let's assume the player is free falling and accelerating under gravity of 9.8 m/s)**

With this data, the minimum displacement is **1 pixel = 0.1m**, so the end result is no movement for a lot of frames. If the speed is constant, no movement occurs at all.
For now, I used a multiplicative factor to scale my calculations up, but is there a better approach to deal with this?
Basically, my question is: how should I handle (small) fractions of movement in a consistent and realistic way?

EDIT: The solution should be to always use `float`s(`double`s) for every physical variable including object position in space and convert to integer pixel coordinate only as a last step when it's time to render. This way in the physical model everything works, even fine movement.
Mauro

Comment: Do you save the player position with `int`s or `float`s (or `double`s)?

Comment: I use ints for the  x, y coordinates of the player and floats for calculations, but even if I used floats or doubles for position the actual display coordinates are just integers. Internally, I calculate everything with floating point numbers but the actual display has only a specified integer resolution and here lies my problem.

Comment: What is the result you expect from the animation? You are limited by the pixel raster you have and a pixel can have only a specific color. You can "zoom in" for a smoother animation, but when you "zoom out" you have the same problem even worst.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a problem of scale. I'm still new to this, but maybe I can maintain the right relative measurements and simply scale the final result to fit the current screen resolution? So, internally I use real world measures for everything and then I scale everything for the final presentation? But I cannot avoid this problem if the movement is small relative to the dimensions of the scene on screen, is that so?

Comment: You might want to check https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for questions like https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87353/how-do-you-move-a-sprite-in-sub-pixel-increments

Comment: Thanks for the link. I edited my question with the insights I gathered there and now I think I have a better understanding of how to approach the simulation the right way. Much appreciated.